# Can a high quality JPEG be converted to a low quality JPEG without decoding it?

Tags: c, image, jpeg, raspberry-pi

I have a webcam which delivers high quality MJPEG.

I need to send small, low quality, JPEGs over the network.  My hardware is a Raspberry Pi (700MHz ARM).  I want the code to use as little CPU power, and add as little latency as possible.  I could decode and re-encode each frame, but this may be wasteful...

Is it logically possible to reduce the quality of a JPEG image without decoding it?

i.e. can I find and remove chunks of 'fine-grained' data and then fix-up field lengths and checksums?

Comment: In case you are attempting something along the lines of [**this**](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/stream-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-to-web-browsers-even-on-ios-and-android), you can configure the camera to output lower quality JPEGs with the help of the `-q` param to [`raspistill`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam/RaspiStill.c#L338).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Theoretically yes.

But practically, any system capable of doing that would be capable of decoding and re-encoding the jpeg within reasonable time.

Any code that attempts to reduce the jpeg quality directly would need to have the following 2 phases :

**Phase1**. Parse the jpeg file to identify various markers and the payload.
**Phase2**. Strip the high-entropy parts of the payload and prepare new file.

- Phase1 above would have the complexity of a jpeg decoder.
- Any potential performance gains would have to be gained by implementing Phase2 to execute faster than a jpeg encode at a lower Q-value. This is not an attractive proposition because the encoding time decreases with a reduced Q-factor<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vK02.jpg)</sup>. In other words, encoding image-data at lower Q-factor is almost always faster than attempting to strip the image-data encoded at a higher Q-factor.

---

An alternative approach (similar to what you have in mind) will work nicely for a subset of jpeg images - **Progressive JPEGs** (which by the way, are simply [**awesome**](http://blog.patrickmeenan.com/2013/06/progressive-jpegs-ftw.html)).

> In progressive JPEG images, components are encoded in multiple scans. The compressed data for each component is placed in a minimum of 2 and as many as 896 scans. The initial scans create a rough version of the image, while subsequent scans refine it.

[image: Baseline vs. Progressive JPEGs]

Essentially the number of scans determines the quality of the jpeg as the latter scans improve upon the previous scans by adding in the fine-grained high-entropy info to the image.

In the jpeg stream, each scan is denoted by a SOS (Start Of Scan marker) which is essentially 2 bytes `0xFF`, `0xDA` followed by the payload i.e the encoded data contained in that particular scan (or "slice" to be technically accurate).

To reduce the size of a progressive jpeg, one could simply read-in a pre-determined number of scans/slices from the jpeg file and drop the latter ones at the cost of quality. This can be implemented while reading in the jpeg data from the file or later in a single pass over the encoded data.

---

<sub>**References** :

1. [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG).

2. Gregory K. Wallace. The JPEG Still Picture Compression Standard. The Communication
of the ACM, 34(10), Oct. 1991.

3. [ece.ucdavis.edu/cerl/ReliableJPEG/Cung/jpeg.html](http://www.ece.ucdavis.edu/cerl/ReliableJPEG/Cung/jpeg.html)</sub>

Comment: Ensuring that all JPEGs are progressive beforehand is definitely the best method; with 5 scans, you can easily dynamically adjust the bits being sent. Not always possible, sadly.

Comment: However, I'd say that you're wrong about the complexity of phase1 & 2, because the IDCT and DCT plus two RGB<->YUV conversions is 80-90% of the complexity. Decoding, Dequantizing, Requantizing, and Encoding is MUCH faster, and extremely simple math. JPEG hasn't been CPU bound for a while, but back in the day that was common; it's also slightly higher quality than merely dropping coeffs like progressive.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for request a comment.

Well, Motion-JPEG is actually the highest quality moving picture format available,
and it has great potential for further processing and transformation which is currently
far from being realized.

There are several aspects to consider, I can give you three particular examples here.

First, there is great opportunity for runtime performance boost by platform-specific optimization of the JPEG codec on assembler level, as is demonstrated here:

- [SnappyCam iPhone app](http://www.snappylabs.com/labs.html)
- [iPhone King of Speed](http://www.snappylabs.com/blog/snappycam/2013/07/31/iphone-king-of-speed/)

By extreme software optimization for the particular ARM platform this app achieves greater speed than even the dedicated hardware solution for this purpose on this device!

Second, there are applications which can significantly reduce the size of given JPEG images at same resolution and same *apparent* quality, by optimizing the quantization tables.
Search for ThinPic App and JPEGmini (it appears that I'm not allowed to post more links
here).

These are all commercial offerings and so there is no free source code available.

Third, I had a requirement to **reduce the resolution** of given Motion-JPEG files.
They were shot at 1280x720 on a digital camera, and I wanted to playback them in a window
on screen in half size at 640x360.

I used the new SmartScale feature introduced with JPEG 8 to achieve this reduction with no
loss of quality, by simply cutting off the high-frequency coefficients of the DCT block.
The reduction in the size of the resulting file wasn't that great (about 20% smaller),
but it is considerably less demanding to playback 640x360 with 4x4 DCT instead of
1280x720 with 8x8 DCT.

The transcode was done with a specially adapted *VirtualDub* and *jpegtran* source code
(the new memory source and destination managers of the IJG code were introduced with
this use case). The playback is done with a specially adapted *ffdshow* source code.
This is an experimental setup for demonstration and is far from a distributable state.

Regards,
Guido Vollbeding,
Organizer Independent JPEG Group

Comment: Thanks for the info. Functionality like JPEGmini/ThinPic seems easy to implement(not sure about the encoder performance though). [**Apparently**](http://encode.ru/threads/1470-jpegmini-com), all they do is reduce the Q-factor to around 83%, enable Huffman-optimisation and use some custom quantization tables". The **Smartscale** feature sounds the most promising though.

Comment: Thanks Guido for your answer and emailed links.  What I'm trying to do is minimize latency on a stream of tiny JPEG images, sent over UDP from a Raspberry Pi with USB webcam.  I should have explained that I'm looking for C libraries, rather than online services.

Comment: The question is **how** they determine the custom quantization tables. They seem to keep that as their business secret. **SmartScale** is more for the image quality aware people, less for the bit counters.

Comment: I know and I develop the IJG JPEG library (we are now at **[generation 9](http://www.infai.org/jpeg/)**), but I wanted to show you that there is still great potential regarding JPEG technology which is not yet realized in available C libraries. And imagine the result if you combined all the three mentioned features!!!